# How does parameter selection work in LassoCV when nothing is supplied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Basically, I am wondering how LassoCV in sklearn chooses values of alpha (the shrinkage parameter) when none are provided. When you run the statement,

```
reg = LassoCV(cv = 5) # cv = 5 for 5 fold cross val
reg.fit(X, Y)
```

I am happy with the results that I am getting; however, I am curious as to how the model chooses the optimal alpha. Is it simply iterating through all alphas in a range with a given tolerance?

Other than that, I also wanted to ask what happens when you supply it values of alpha or use the n_alphas parameter, i.e.:

```
reg = LassoCV(cv = 5, alphas = [.1, .2, .001, ...])
reg = LassoCV(cv = 5, n_alphas = 100)
```

How does it determine which one of these alpha values are best? What alphas does it cycle through when providing a number of alphas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> How does it determine which one of these alpha values are best?

It goes through  a cross-validation procedure with all submitted values of `alpha`, and returns the one with the greatest `score`, which, according to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.score), is the coefficient of determination R^2.

> What alphas does it cycle through when providing a number of alphas?

It's easy to see with a simple example; asking for only `n_alphas=5` for simplicity, we get:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(noise=4, random_state=0)
reg = LassoCV(cv=5, n_alphas=5, random_state=0).fit(X, y)
```

According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html), one of the attributes of the fitted object is:

> **alphas_ : *numpy array, shape (n_alphas,)***
>
> The grid of alphas used for fitting

So, here we have:

```
reg.alphas_
# result:
array([  6.92751635e+01,   1.23190597e+01,   2.19067302e+00,
         3.89562872e-01,   6.92751635e-02])
```

The exact values are again indirectly determined by the parameter `eps`, which has a default value of `0.001`; again from the docs:

> **eps : *float, optional***
>
> Length of the path. `eps=1e-3` means that `alpha_min / alpha_max = 1e-3`.

So, essentially it sets a grid of possible aplhas such as the ratio of the minimum to the maximum value is equal to `eps`, here `0.001`; let's verify that this is the case in our simple example:

```
reg.alphas_[4]/reg.alphas_[0]
# result
0.00099999999999999959
```

which, for all practical purposes, is indeed equal to `0.001`.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for your answer. Now what happens when I provide neither n_alphas or a table of alphas to test from. How does it determine the alpha value? Also, when using n_alphas - I understand the length of the path explanation that you gave - but how does it find which alphas on the path to use?

Comment: @tester9271 if you don't provide anything, it uses the default value of `n_alphas=100` (again, see the docs). As for the rest, I am not sure - the max and min values seem to always be the same irrespectively of the grid length, but I can't say how exactly they are chosen. In any case, you should not take this very seriously - it is just a convenience; you should always prefer to provide exact values of `aplha` yourself.